# Why does this simple C++ code segfault?

Tags: c++, templates, std

Here is the **a.h** header:

```
#include <string>

template <typename L>
class A
{
    L l;

public:
    A() : l("a-text") {}
    const std::string get() const { l.get(); } // <<<< Edit: missing return!
};
```

And here is **a.cpp**:

```
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>

class L {
    const std::string v;

public:
    L(const std::string& v_): v(v_) {}
    const std::string get() const { return v; }
};

int main() {
    L l("l-text");
    std::cout << l.get().c_str() << std::endl;

    A<L> a;
    std::cout << a.get().c_str() << std::endl; // <<<< - this will report Segmentation fault

    return 0;
}
```

The first `std::cout` will work okay displaying *l-text*
Yet the second `std::cout` will report Segmentation fault instead of displaying *a-text*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are assuming that the template parameter type has either text literal constructor or string constructor.  This may cause issues when the type parameter doesn't deal with strings, like `int`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's true, however in solutions, the name of the class (typename) will suggest you what it expects. For example you may call it "Logger" and this way tell the class user that you expect a logger class that has specific requirements. Anyway, I have blew it because forgetting to call return, and was crashed by the downgrades. Thanks for reaching me, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Turn on your warnings**. You're missing a `return` statement here:

```
const std::string get() const { l.get(); }
```

Comment: Plus you are outputting the string pointer and not the data

Comment: @Vittorio: Darn. This was simple g++ a.cpp build, and no warning was being displayed. I assumed the default level is more than 0. Thanks!

Comment: @Grzegorz: always build with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`. Mark my answer as accepted if it satisfied you

Comment: @Vittorio: I have an environment that does it already all. I run a quick test on a sample code to check something that did not compile, and run into this segfault. Did not even think using other options. Thanks again!

Comment: @manatttta: cout interprets a char* as a pointer to a C-style string, so should print the string appropriately, not the pointer

Comment: @manatttta - I hope you have not down-voted my question as it was legit, while I calling `c_str()` on `std::string` is the right way to get stuff to be printed.

Comment: Your question probably got downvoted because you posted on StackOverflow before turning on warnings :)

Comment: @Vittorio: Thanks again. I have upvoted you and will mark as the answer then will delete my post for people are hitting me with down votes and messing up stats.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: That would explain it :)

Comment: @Grzegorz You won't be able to delete this question as it has an up voted answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I see. That's fair. Well, I will take the hit then. At some point I hope they will stop down voting me. Maybe I will get a badge or something with the biggest number of down votes, lol!

Comment: @Grzegorz I wouldn't bet on it.  There is much worse cr.. creations out there on SO;)

Comment: @Grzegorz In addition to what was already mentioned in the answer and comments, not `return`ing from non-void function is undefined behavior: i.e. anything can happen (including, but not limited to: segfault, seeming to work correctly, corrupting memory, etc.).